# What is the diffuse ionized gas?

Tags: interstellar-medium, gas

I've been trying to find a clean definition what people mean by when they talk about *diffuse ionized gas in the interstellar medium*, but I couldn't find anything so far.
Apparently it's supposed to be trivial.

Is it simply ionized gas, mixed with non-ionized gas in the ISM through the process of diffusion?

Comment: PLease post links to examples of this usage.

Comment: It's not mixed via diffusion, it is diffuse, as in rarefied, as in the opposite of dense.

Comment: @FJC that cleared it up! Didn't know that was a synonym for rarefied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "diffuse ionized gas" (DIG) is another term for the phase of the interstellar medium (ISM) usually called the **warm ionized medium (WIM)**. With a temperature of the order $10^4\,\mathrm{K}$, but extenting to lower and higher temperatures, it is hot enough to keep hydrogen ionized, and various metals exist as low-ionization species, such as S II, N II, and O II, and even (weak) O III (e.g. [Hill et al. 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0369); [Zang et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02000); [Weilbacher et al. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04450)).

Rough pressure equilibrium with the other phases of the ISM results in characteristic densities of $0.1\,\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$, but typical ranges are an order of magnitude to both sides.

A review of the DIG/WNM can be found in [Haffner et al. (2009)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0941).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it means anything special.  Take, for example, the claim  at  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_cloud)

> An interstellar cloud is generally an accumulation of gas, plasma, and
>   dust in our and other galaxies. Put differently, an interstellar cloud
>   is a denser-than-average region of the interstellar medium, (ISM), the
>   matter and radiation that exists in the space between the star systems
>   in a galaxy. Depending on the density, size, and temperature of a
>   given cloud, its hydrogen can be neutral, making an H I region;
>   ionized, or plasma making it an H II region; or molecular, which are
>   referred to simply as molecular clouds, or sometimetimes dense clouds.
>   Neutral and ionized clouds are sometimes also called diffuse clouds.
>   An interstellar cloud is formed by the gas and dust particles from a
>   red giant in its later life.

As well as another [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium)

> In all phases, the interstellar medium is extremely tenuous by
>   terrestrial standards. In cool, dense regions of the ISM, matter is
>   primarily in molecular form, and reaches number densities of $10^6$
>   molecules per $cm^3$ (1 million molecules per cm3). In hot, diffuse
>   regions of the ISM, matter is primarily ionized, and the density may
>   be as low as $10^{−4}$ ions per $cm^3$. Compare this with a number density of
>   roughly $10^{19}$ molecules per cm3 for air at sea level, and $10^{10}$
>   molecules per $cm^3$ (10 billion molecules per $cm^3$) for a laboratory
>   high-vacuum chamber.

Comment: Carl, you need to fix the numbers - e.g. 10^19 rather than 1019.

Comment: @Chappo thanks - I didn't pay attention when I cut/pasted